# I can't send mail using SendGrid in nodejs app (glitch)

Tags: sendgrid, nodejs-8.11

I am using **SendGrid API** in `nodejs`

Here my **server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
require('dotenv').config();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static('public'));

// http://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html
app.get("/", (req, res)=> {
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'test@gmail.com',
  from: 'test@test.com',
  subject: 'Welcome',
  text: 'text',
  html: '  <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; background: #2874f0"><style> @font-face {font-family: "Google Sans";font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;src: url("https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/googlesans/v6/4UaGrENHsxJlGDuGo1OIlL3Kwp5eKQtGBlc.woff2") format("woff2");unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;} @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=abc")</style><table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;"><tr><td style="padding:20px; color: #fff; font-family: Google Sans"> Hello!</td></tr></table></body>',
};
sgMail.send(msg);
});
// listen for requests :)
var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

In my **.env** file

```
SENDGRID_KEY= MYKEY
```

> I am getting an error env: line 1: SENDGRID_KEY: command not found

Answer (score 0):

I have often had similar problems when I left a space in my **.env** file. There may be spaces in the variable values only if **"they are within quotes"**.